# JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, express

So I have Been Writing this function all night, its goal is to find and sort data from two tables and then return an array of objects containing my needed data
But the array keep showing empty

```
 router.post('/find/', (req,res,next)=>{
  try {
     // Return an array of Hotels in the Region
    hotels.find({region:"wuse"}).then(hotel=>{
      const finalArr = []
      for(var i = 0; i< hotel.length;i++){
        rooms.find({hotel:hotel[i]._id,price:{$lt : 29000}}).then(rooms=>{
          for(var j = 0; j <rooms.length; j++ ){
           // Push to the arr 
            finalArr.push(rooms[j])
            console.log(rooms[j]);// Its Works 
          }
        }).catch(err =>{
          console.log(err);
        })
      }
      console.log(finalArr);// And This Return [] an Empty Array
      res.end()
    }).catch(err =>{
      console.log(err);
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
})
```

I have used Async/await,
append(),
forEach() and Promise.all()

any solution would.

Comment: `Promise.all` will work just fine here - map each `rooms.find` to a Promise and then call `Promise.all` on the array of Promises

Comment: can you please write a code snippet cause I tried that already

Comment: `Promise.all(hotel.map(item => rooms.find(...))).then((allResults) => { ...`

Comment: hey Tried it Still Not Appending or concat to the array  ```let finalArr = []
      Promise.all(hotel.map(item =>{
        rooms.find({hotel:item._id,price:{$lt : 29000}}).then((allResult)=>{
          finalArr.push(allResult)
        })
      }))```